# Amavis-new whitelist

Tags: amavis, whitelist

Hi to the Linux community. I'm coming from a Windows Server background so have mercy.

I'm attempting to whitelist some domains and although I know this isn't the best way of doing so its just a one off for a couple of domains so I thought it would be the quickest way of doing so. Current setup:

Amavis is used to pass emails off the ClamAV and SpamAssasin, currently I make changes in /etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user, as this will overide other settings.

Have created a whitelist file that looks like this:

```
.domaintowhitelist.com
.domain2towhitelist.com
```

In the 50-user config file:

Have tried variants like this:

```
read_hash(\%whitelist_sender, '/etc/amavis/whitelist');
read_hash(\%virus_lovers, '/etc/amavis/whitelist');
```

And restarting amavis after making those changes. Am I going about this the wrong way? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I know this is four years later, but can you explain the syntax `\%whitelist_sender`? I can't find that anywhere in the amavis docs. It's always just `read_hash(<file>)`.

Answer (score 7):

I do whitelisting at the MTA level (in my case postfix) rather than at the amavisd level.  In my postfix/main.cf file, I have:

```
header_checks=pcre:/etc/postfix/whitelist.pcre
```

Inside whitelist.pcre, I have the following syntax:

```
user@example.com FILTER  SMTP:[127.0.0.1]:10025
```

where **SMTP:[127.0.0.1]:10025** is the transport in master.cf that filtered mail is reinjected into the postfix system.  My reasoning to do that is if certain messages are not to be checked for anything, I don't want amavisd to touch it.

Comment: That's an odd looking pcre statement. Use `/user@example\.com/ FILTER  smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025`

Comment: Haven't you ended up with a transport error ? I had `Jan 29 12:12:00 messagerie postfix/error[27477]: 9A1783A80088:to=<a.chaouche@domain.tld>, relay=none,relay=none, delay=1.6, delays=1.5/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)`

Comment: it should be "smtp" in minor case, otherwise you'd get a mail transport unavailable error. The logs may contain a line that looks like this : `warning: connect to transport private/SMTP: No such file or directory`
`

Comment: worked for me, the only thing I changed was instead of smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025, I used lmtp:inet:localhost:24

Answer (score 1):

I never used a setup an external file. When I had to implement a whitelist, i simply used one of the form listed here:

http://www.akadia.com/services/postfix_amavisd.html#Globally%20Sender%20Whitelists%20and%20Blacklists

and especially this one:
@whitelist_sender_maps = (['.example.org', '.example.net']);

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have applied that line to my 50-user config file and restarted amavis but tried to send my mailbox anotehr 'virus' and exe in a zip file and get the BANNED bounce back message. Is there any way to check if my sending domain is being whitelisted? Thanks

Comment: As stated here http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/amavisd-new-docs.html#wblist :

"It should be emphasized that whitelisting (and blacklisting) only affects spam checks. It has no influence on other checks such as virus, banned or header checks. Infected mail from whitelisted sender would still be blocked if our policy is to block viruses."

If you want to bypass everything, go and check policy banks:

http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/amavisd-new-docs.html#pbanks